# How to implement global route change handler in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

I'm working on MAUI app and want to execute some code every time when I change url. How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App.razor`, Add these lines of code:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@implements IDisposable

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized() => NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;

    private void OnLocationChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code
        Console.WriteLine("Location Changed...");
    }

    public void Dispose() => NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
}
```